# SEO: Firefox addon/plugin to see Google results with a position number?

Tags: seo, google, firefox, yahoo

Do you know a Firefox addon that adds position number to Google/Yahoo results?

When I do SEO report for `www.some-site.example` by keyphrase "some-site" I usually show results in blocks of 100 results per page. Then using browser find box I search for `some-site.example`, if found in page I see its position, but **I have to count by hand the number of results before (or after) it to know the exact position number**.

It would be handful a simple addon that adds a number positioning before each result like:

```
1. Result blah blah
Snippet...
url

2. Result blah blah
Snippet...
url

etc.
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using this GreaseMonkey script and see if it works for you.

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/10687

Comment: +1 GreaseMonkey is ideal for this type of browser behavior modification

Answer (score 0):

SEO for Firefox, shows that and much more as well as allows you to export the data as CSV.

Comment: It seems too complicate, I don't like the idea to subscribe to the nth web service. I was seraching for a simple addon. Thanks anyway for your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Try [SEOQuake](http://www.seoquake.com/) which is a plugin for (most) major browsers. It allows you to see directly on the search results various statistics for each site (yours also). Using `Tools>SEOQuake>Keyword Density` you can generate a live report of a given web page, which creates a statistical breakdown of your keywords by value.

Other features include performing a Diagnosis which actually suggests in plain-user text, exactly what you can do to improve your SEO.

Comment: SEOQuake does everything except what I asked.